# Keystone: There is a way to get the email address once I have the auth token?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, keystone, openstack-horizon

Hello I don't know if this question has been asked but I couldn't find an answer, I'm using the REST API v2.0 that Keystone has as authentication method for my application and I need the user's email address. So do you know if this is possible?? or there is a way of doing this I have been reading the API docs and I found that you can get the user details but you have to be an admin for that. Thanks

http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-identity-v2.html#admin-users

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem in keystone v2 is that policy does not get enforced for certain API's. Due to this, most of the user/project related APIs are confined to "admin" role.
I would suggest you to use keystone v3 API and you can tweak the policy.json as per your requirement.

```
policy.json is located at :  /etc/keystone/policy.json
```

Note: Keystone V3 is stable and you can use it without any problems.